# Android sending data to Activity via Local Service

Tags: java, android, android-service

I have an app that receives gcm push notifications. I also have a check in place that if the app is currently open, it does not create the notification. In Android, is it possible in my push service to tell the current activity (IF Available/connected), that a new notification has arrived, refresh your list with the new content? If this is possible, I believe I am on the right path with using IBinders on my service. The thing about that is I am confused on how the Service Calls the Activity (I understand vice verse). Thanks in advance if anyone could help!

Just to be clear. I am trying to tell the activity about a new push message.

Service

```
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    GcmIntentService getService() {
        return GcmIntentService.this;
    }
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
```

Client (Activity)

```
 private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
        // This is called when the connection with the service has been
        // established, giving us the service object we can use to
        // interact with the service.  Because we have bound to a explicit
        // service that we know is running in our own process, we can
        // cast its IBinder to a concrete class and directly access it.
        mBoundService = ((GcmIntentService.LocalBinder)service).getService();

        // Tell the user about this for our demo.
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
        // This is called when the connection with the service has been
        // unexpectedly disconnected -- that is, its process crashed.
        // Because it is running in our same process, we should never
        // see this happen.
        mBoundService = null;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Disconnected",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
void doBindService() {
    // Establish a connection with the service.  We use an explicit
    // class name because we want a specific service implementation that
    // we know will be running in our own process (and thus won't be
    // supporting component replacement by other applications).
    bindService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            GcmIntentService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mIsBound = true;
}

void doUnbindService() {
    if (mIsBound) {
        // Detach our existing connection.
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mIsBound = false;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    doUnbindService();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

In your service class have a variable of type YourActivity

```
MyActivity myActivity = null;
```

In your `onServiceConnected` method set this myActivity variable on the service, obtained through the binder.

```
mBoundService.myActivity = MyActivity.this; // or something similar
```

Now your service has a pointer to your activity!!! YEah!!

Inside your activity, create a function, the body of this function should refresh the UI with data.

Finally, when the service detects new data, call:

```
if (myActivity)
    myActivity.refreshMyData();
```

When unbinding, remember to set the myActivity variable to null, otherwise the previous code will fail.

Comment: Thanks! Worked as expected.